# Html5 Video Player is not working in Safari

Tags: javascript, html5-video

I am implementing a video player using `<video>`. This is working in Chrome, Firefox, and Internet Explorer but is not working in Safari.

```js
$("#vdsourceVideoPath").attr("src", "http://localhost:3000/Documents/upc and shelf info_0001.mp4");
var player = document.getElementById('vdTrainingVideoPlayer');
player.load();
player.play();
```

```html
<video id="vdTrainingVideoPlayer" class="vdTrainingVideoPlayer" controls="controls" autoplay="autoplay">
  <source id="vdsourceVideoPath" src="" type="video/mp4" />
</video>
```

`player.load()` and `player.play()` method are giving errors in Safari.

Comment: "is giving error" — And you didn't think it worth mentioning **what the error message said**?!

Comment: You could just use YouTube or something similar and then use the embed code. Which will work cross browser

Comment: @Quentin sir it is not giving any error it just not working. that's it.

Comment: @M_Griffiths sir would you please provide me the code or link.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @AbhishekSingh — If it isn't giving any error, why did you say "player.load() and player.play() method are giving errors in Safari." in the question?

Answer (score -2):

You could use the YouTube player
Use the youtube site to find the video you want
Click the 'Share' button below the video
Click the 'Embed' button next to the link they show you
Copy the iframe code given and paste it into the html of your web page.

Check out this [link](http://www.simplehtmlguide.com/youtube.php)

This article gives a good run through of implementing a html5 video player
http://www.creativebloq.com/html5/build-custom-html5-video-player-9134473

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/14089147)

Comment: Yeah I know it doesn't, however the op did ask for a link so that's what they got. Honestly people are so rude in this forum.